# Unknown work of Nöbeling on topological/Hausdorff dimension

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, ho.history-overview, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}^n$ denote the Hausdorff measure, $\dim_H X$ the Hausdorff dimension, and $\dim X$ the topological dimension of $X$.

A well known result of
Szpilrajn (He changed his name to Marczewski while hiding from Nazi persecution) proved in [S] asserts that
if $\mathcal{H}^{n+1}(X)=0$, then  the topological dimension of $X$ is at most $n$.

Szpilrajn's proof is reproduced in [Theorem 7.3, HW] and [[Theorem 8.15](https://books.google.com/books?id=5oXlBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA63), H].

Szpilrajn however, mentions in [S] that his argument is based on Nöbeling's proof of a weaker result that topological dimension is bounded from above by the Hausdorff dimension of a metric space. However, he did not provide any reference to Nöbeling's work.

There is also no reference to Nöbeling's work in the book by Hurewicz and Wallman.

> **Question.** Does anybody know the reference to the original work of Nöbeling?

**[H] J. Heinonen,**
*Lectures on analysis on metric spaces.* Universitext. Springer-Verlag, New York, 2001.

**[HW] W. Hurewicz, H. Wallman,** *Dimension Theory.* Princeton Mathematical Series, v. 4. Princeton University Press, Princeton, N. J., 1941.

**[S] E. Szpilrajn,** [La dimension et la mesure](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-fmv28i1p11bwm), *Fund. Math.* 28 (1937), 81--89.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler yes, Szpilrajn references this paper in the introduction to [S], and the result quoted by OP is the first theorem in this paper.

Comment: The reference given by Francois Ziegler is: Nöbeling, G.
Hausdorffsche und mengentheoretische Dimension. (German) JFM 57.0749.02
Ergebnisse math. Kolloquium Wien 3, 24-25 (1931).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler your second "reprint" link is a Google books link, which in my case only yields the 1st page (the second is referred as "not available" — I guess availability means Google decides when and to whom it makes it available)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, the sought for paper is:

Nöbeling, G., Hausdorffsche und mengentheoretische Dimension, Ergebnisse math. Kolloquium Wien 3, 24-25 (1931).

And here is a ``translation" (to English and to modern math exposition standards, if such a thing exists.) What is called the set-theoretical dimension is defined inductively: dim of the empty set is $-1$, and we set $\dim M = k$ if $k$ is the least integer with the property that every point of $M$ has arbitrarily small (open) neighborhoods whose dim is $k-1$.

### Hausdorff and set-theoretical dimension. By George Nöbeling.

Let $M$ be a subset of the Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$. One covers $M$ by finitely or countably (infinitely) many balls $K_j$, with diameters $d_j < \rho$, for $p \leq n$ (any non-negative number) form the sum $ \sum d_j^p $. Let $ L_p(\rho, M)$ be the infimum of such sums for all such coverings. Put 
$$
L_p (M) = \lim_{\rho \to 0} L_p (\rho, M) .
$$
Obviously there is exactly one number $p= p (M)$ such that for every $q > p$, $L_q (M) = 0$ and for every number $q <p$, $L_q (M) = \infty$. We call this clearly defined number $p$ the Hausdorff dimension of the set $M$ and claim that

**THEOREM**: For any set $M$, the Hausdorff dimension is at least equal to the set-theoretical dimension.

**PROOF.** The proof is done by induction on the set-theoretical dimension $\dim M$. For every $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots\} $ we prove that if $M$ is a set with $\dim M \geq k$ then $p(M) \geq k$.

For $k=0$ this is obvious thanks to $ p (M) \geq 0.$ Suppose the claim is true for $k$. We must thus prove that if $M$ is any set with $\dim M \geq (k + 1)$, then $p(M) \geq k+1$.

Since $M$ is at least $(k+1)$-dimensional, there exit a point $P$ of $M$ and a number $r_0$, such that for every $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere $S_r$, with the radius $r \leq r_0$ the intersection $M \cap S_r$ is at least $k$-dimensional. [*Otherwise, every point of $M$ would have arbitrarily small open neighborhoods whose boundaries had dim $k-1$ or less, and so by definition $M$ would have dimension less than or equal to $k$.*], and therefore according to the induction hypothesis that
$$
\forall r \leq r_0, \; p (M \cap S_r) \geq k \, .
$$

For each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\{K_{ij}\}_j$ be a covering of the set $M$ by spheres of diameter $d_{ij} < \frac{1}{i}$. For a number $q < k +1$ and an $0 < x \leq r_0$ we set 
    $$
f_{ij} (x) = 
\begin{cases}
d_{ij}^{q-1} & \text{if $S_x \cap K_{ij} \neq \emptyset $ ,}\\
0 & \text{Otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

We also set 
$$
s_i (x) = \sum f_{ij} (x).
$$
Obviously,
$$
s_i(x) \geq L_{q-1}(1/i,S_x \cap M) \, .
$$
Since $ p (M \cap S_r) \geq k > q-1 $, it follows from the induction hypothesis that
$$
\forall x \in (0,r_0], \; \lim_{i \to \infty} s_i(x) = \infty \, .
$$

Thus,
$$
   \sum_j \int_0^{r_0} f_{ij}(x) \, dx = \int_0^{r_0} s_i(x) \, dx  \xrightarrow{i \to \infty} \infty \, .
$$
Now observe that $f_{ij} (x) = d_{ij}^{q-1}$ for $x$ from an interval whose length is at most $d_{ij}$ -- the diameter of $K_{ij}$ -- and otherwise $f_{ij} (x) = 0.$ Therefore, 
$$
\sum_j d_{ij}^{q} = \sum_j \int_0^{d_{ij}} d_{ij}^{q-1} \, dx \geq \sum_j \int_0^{r_0} f_{ij}(x) \, dx  \, .
$$
and hence,
$$
\sum_j d_{ij}^{q}  \xrightarrow{i \to \infty} \infty.
$$
Since this is true for any coverings $K_{ij}$, we conclude
$$
L_q(M) = \infty \implies p(M) \geq q \, .
$$

Since $q <k + 1$ was arbitrary we have shown that $p (M) \geq  k + 1$. This concludes the induction and proves our theorem. $\Box$

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be:

- *Nöbeling, G.*, Hausdorffsche und mengentheoretische Dimension, Ergebnisse math. Kolloquium Wien 3, 24-25 (1931). [ZBL57.0749.02](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:57.0749.02).

Google shows [the first](//books.google.com/books?id=oakkBgAAQBAJ&ots=cZINKQCxR7&pg=PA180&dq=%22Hausdorffsche+und+mengentheoretische+Dimension%22) and sporadically [the second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvLls.png) page (19 lines) from this reprint:

- *Menger, Karl*, Results of a mathematical colloquium, Wien: Springer. ix, 470 S. (1998). [ZBL0917.01024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0917.01024).