# English translation of Hasse's "Arithmetische Theorie der kubischen Zahlkorper auf klassenkorpertheoretischer Grundlage"

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, class-field-theory, number-fields

I want to read through Hasse's paper about cubic number fields: *Arithmetische Theorie der kubischen Zahlkorper auf klassenkorpertheoretischer Grundlage*, Mathematische Zeitschrift **31** (1930) pages 565-582 ([EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/168196)). But unfortunately, I am not proficient in German. Hence can someone give reference to an English translation or some other resource which have comparable content in English? I tried searching on the internet but did not find any such resource. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use Google translate. I translated the first page of the article and this is the result (I did not make any changes. This is the verbatim copy from Google translate). Of course, the result is not perfect, but it is possible to understand once you know what you are reading. I hope it can help.

My student used Google translate to translate an old paper of Nöbeling and without knowing any German he did a good job: https://mathoverflow.net/a/360522/121665

[image]

> Arithmetic theory of cubic number fields on the basis of class body
> theory
>
> Voa Helmut Hasse in Halle.
>
> Content.
>
> Introduction.
>
> w 1. Tabular listing of the facts a t w 2. The invariant ~ w 3. The
> arithmetic as a function of the invariants. w 4. Cubic number fields
> of given discriminants.
>
> Introduction.
>
> The cubic number fields are the simplest of all Used for many
> non-Galois numerals and more or more has been investigated less
> thoroughly ~). The key to their treatment lies in the fact that the
> corresponding Galois bodies are above their square Partial bodies are
> Abelian. Now that the theory of relative Abelschen Zablk6rper dutch
> Messrs Takagi 2) and Artin S) to one has come to a certain conclusion,
> it wold loosely, leaning on it,

Comment: I would also add DeepL as an option for translating from German to English.

Comment: I was on the verge to suggest using it too.